# Verify existence of message in a Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I wish to avoid sending duplicate messages to a Kafka topic.

What is the ideal way to achieve it ?

Using Java client for Apache Kafka, is there anyway to verify if a message exists before invoking **KafkaProducer.send**

I am referring to this [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Kafka `0.10.1`), there is no way to have exactly-once guarantees on write with Kafka. No matter what workaround you want to do, there will be always be a gap and you can end up with either lost messages or duplicates.

However, Kafka will add an [idempotent producer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging) (planned for `0.10.2`) that will allow you to avoid duplicate writes. The target date for `0.10.2` release is [beginning 2017](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Time+Based+Release+Plan).

Comment: Is it a good idea to export the data from Kafka topic to DB and query to verify it's existence ?

Comment: You could verify it's existence just reading the data back with a consumer, too. But this is super expensive and slow. However, there is not good solution that gives good performance right now. You will need to wait for idempotent Producer. For know, it seems to be good to accept duplicate write and design your downstream consumers accordingly and filter out duplicates there.

Answer (score 0):

It is impractical for you to check whether the same message has been delivered every time you send a new one. Think it another way: you could invoke KafkaProducer.send method with a callback notifying you of the success or failure.

Comment: This approach is not save. Even in case of success, there might be no callback to the producer if a failure in the producer happens right after a successful write, but before the callback is triggered. Need to downvote this. Will add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much out of scope for Kafka. You need to do that using a different storage that provides proper indexing for random access.
Depending on your needs, that can be (distributed) cache, a key-value store or whatever.

You'll probably want to do that on the consumer-side rather than producer, as different consumers may use different strategies for de-duplication (and some consumers may simply tolerate duplicates).

Comment: The question is about writing into Kafka and not into a external system.